# Run JS When Use Shift + Tabs to Parent Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have a drop-down menu that I show whenever the user tabs around. Now I'm trying to add functionality to hide the drop-down menu whenever the user Shift + Tabs back to the Parent Item. I've tried to use `focus()` and `blur()` but it runs Before it actually heads upward, if I'm on the 2nd child item and shift tab back to the first, I get the alert below:

```
$('#menu-main-menu ul.submenu li:first-child a').blur().on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which == 9 && e.shiftKey){
        alert('shift');
    }
});
```

I've also [created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bL1p8gwk/1/) to run this code as an example.

How do I run some JS Code whenever the user Shift + Tabs Back to the Parent Item in a List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue is that the user moves focus away from a child item to a parent item, but the child item disappears when it should stay visible. The solution is to use `setTimeout` before hiding the menu item. The parent item needs to listen for "focus" events on itself, and then cancel the `setTimeout`.

When the `setTimeout` expires and executes the callback function, only *then* should the child menu be hidden.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bL1p8gwk/5/

```
$("#mainmenu>li").each(function(idx, menu) {
    console.info("Create menu: ", idx, menu);

    var timeout = 250,
        timer = null,
        $currentItem = null,
        hideMenu = function() {
            console.info("Hide menu " + idx + ": ", $currentItem);
            $currentItem.next("ul.submenu").hide();
            $currentItem.closest("ul.submenu").hide();
            timer = null;
            $currentItem = null;
        };

    $(menu)
        .on("focusout", function(event) {
            $currentItem = $(event.target);
            timer = setTimeout(hideMenu, timeout);
        })
        .on("focusin", function(event) {
            console.info("Focusin: " + idx);

            if (timer) {
                console.info("Stop timer " + idx + ": " + timer);
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }

            console.info("Show sub menu: " + idx);
            $(event.target).next("ul.submenu").show();
        });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul id="mainmenu">
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Products</a>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display: none">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Featured</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Services</a>
        <ul class="submenu" style="display: none">
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Commercial</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Government</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want this:

```
$('#menu-main-menu ul.submenu li:first-child a').blur().on('keyup', function(e){
    if(e.which == 9 && e.shiftKey){

        // Let the event happen, THEN execute this as soon as the browser lets us
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          alert('shift');
        }, 1);

    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, it still fires before I Shift + Tab up to the parent, it fires when I Shift + Tab from Child 2 up to Child 1. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bL1p8gwk/4/). I'm trying to get it to fire when you Shift + Tab from Child 1 to Parent.